# Magento 2 create product attribute that sits outside of 'More information' tab

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm trying to create a product attribute, but I don't want it to sit under the more info tab. I would like to almost be its own block and sit under the 'Add to cart' button.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below lines in your theme layout file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<move element="custom" destination="content" after="product.info.addtocart" />
<container name="custom">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.sec" as="customsec" template="product/view/custom.phtml" />
</container>
<!-- if you want to remove more info tab add this line otherwise ignore -->
<referenceContainer name="product.attributes" remove="true" />
```

Get attribute value in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom.phtml`

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); //atttribute value
$lable = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getStoreLabel(); //attribute lable

echo $value.' : '.$lable;
?>
```

**note:** c_address is my custom attribute

If you want to custmize more info tab, override the below template

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

you can find the declaration in `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: sorry where should custom.phtml sit? Edit: sorry seen where it should go

Comment: Thats worked now I just need to get it to sit in the right place as its not quite bellow the add to cart button. Oh and your just missing a '.' before $lable Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer @Mark